# How to interpolate list with markup in Python string

Tags: python

I am working on this ppython snippet. How can I publish HTML list in `write()` along with hard coded markup on initialing the file?

Basically I want to write to file three

```
<li>apple</li> 
<li>banana</li> 
<li>cherry</li>
```

Here is the code

```
f = open("D:/App/Test.html", "a")
f.write(
"""<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container py-4">
  <ul>
  """
    fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
        for x in fruits:
         print(x)

    """
    </ul></div>
      </body>
    </html>"""
)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to create a template.  Note `{items}` is the location to be inserted:

```py
template = '''\
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='container py-4'>
      <ul>
{items}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
'''
```

Then build the insertion string:

```py
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
items = '\n'.join([f'        <li>{x}</li>' for x in fruits])

with open('test.html','w') as f:
    f.write(template.format(items=items))
```

Output:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='container py-4'>
      <ul>
        <li>apple</li>
        <li>banana</li>
        <li>cherry</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Mark but it looks like there is a Syntax error on `items = '\n'.join([f'        <li>{x}</li>' for x in fruits])` line.

Comment: i guess this depends on the python version ? should run in python3; could fail in pyhton2 (maybe import fstring package ?)

Comment: in python2 you should have the option to it with 
```"\n".join(["<li>{x}</li>".format(x=x) for x in fruits])```

Comment: @Behseini F-string format syntax (`f'...'`) was introduced in Python 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

I remove the commented code to make it easier to read.

You can do it in the following way.

```
f = open("D:/App/Test.html", "a")
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]

list_html= ''.join([f"<li>{i}</li>\n" for i in fruits])

f.write(list_html)
f.close()
```

`.join` converts the list to a string and `f"<li>{i}</li>\n" for i in fruits` goes through all the elements of the loop and makes them in list format

Answer (score 0):

try this. this put a list of strings in your html_code. and build on your logic so you understand whats going on.

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
    
f = ["  <li>{0}</li>".format(i) for i in fruits]

html_list = ""
for x in f:
    html_list += x + "\n  "
    
html_code = """<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container py-4">
  <ul>
  """ + html_list + """
    </ul></div>
      </body>
    </html>"""



for i in html_code.split("\n"):
    print(i)
```